# Do exist positive integers $a < b$ with the following property: Whenever $m, n$ are positive integers with $m^a|n^b$ then $m|n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Decide with justification if there exist positive integers $a < b$ with the following property: Whenever $m, n$ are positive integers with $m^a|n^b$ then $m|n$.

Here's my attempt at a proof:

Assume for the sake of contradiction there are such integers $a < b$. If $m^a = \prod_{i = 1}^r p_i^{ax_i}$ and $n^b = \prod_{i = 1}^r p_i^{by_i}$, we know that $ax_i \le by_i$ for all $1 \le i \le r$ because $m^a \mid n^b$. But, it could be the case that $x_k > y_k$ for some $1 \le k \le r$ which implies that $m \nmid n$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, no positive $a < b$ exist.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you intend to say $m = \prod_{i = 1}^r p_i^{x_i}$ or $m^a = \prod_{i = 1}^r p_i^{ax_i}$ and similarly with $n$?

Comment: $~8^1~$ divides $~4^2,~$ but $~8~$ does not divide $~4.~$

Answer (score 2):

short version. Assuming $a<b$ work, define
$$   m = 2^b \, , \; \; n = 2^a \, .$$

Then $m^a = n^b$  but $m$  does not divide $n$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).